# Using PNG/GIF Images as buttons using AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, imagebutton, flashdevelop

Friends,

I am new to AS3 so pardon me. I am trying to use images as buttons (PNG/GIF images as buttons(simple, toggled and multi-state) - Image change on mouse over, normal and pressed) using AS3 only. I tried to search. All I got is to setting icon of a Button. It would be really great if you can share the code snippet or pointers.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html

Comment: if you'd accept answers, people might be more willing to help you

Comment: Thanks EyeSeeEm. I'll. I din't realize that it's so important. Thanks once again. :-)

Answer (score 2):

There are ways to do this without converting an image to a Movieclip. You can either embed your images inside your SWF using the [Embed] tag....or, a better way, you can load them using the Loader class.

You would load your image like this:

```
var myloader:Loader = new Loader();
myloader.load(new URLRequest("myImage"));
```

...and then you would get its BitmapData like this after the loading completes (use an event listener to catch this):

```
var myBitmapData:BitmapData = Bitmap(myloader.content).bitmapData;
```

A BitmapData object needs a Bitmap container in order for it to be placed on the stage, so you'll need to declare a Bitmap instance using the BitmapData as input.

```
var Bitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(myBitmapData);
```

Since that Bitmap can be added to the stage, you're good to go. You can use that as part of your button class. There's some more Bitmap information [here at 8bitrocket.](http://www.8bitrocket.com/2010/04/12/tutorial-exploring-the-as3-bitmap-class-lesson-1-creating-a-basic-dynamic-tile-sheet/)

This is a nice way of doing it for those of us who don't use Flash CS 5, or any other movieclip creators. I'm making a game in FlashDevelop using this technique and it works well.

Hope this helps as an "actionscript only" method. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

take a png or jpg and convert it to a movieclip.  Give it an instance name.  In this example it will be **myButton**.

then assign it the following code:

```
myButton.buttonMode = true; // gives it a hand cursor

// first param is the event type, second param is the function called
myButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClicked);
myButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, onOver);
myButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, onOut);

function onClicked(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    // do something
}

function onOver(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    // button that was rolled over can be referenced here with
    // evt.target like evt.target.gotoAndPlay('over');
}

function onOut(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    // button that was rolled off of can be referenced here with
    // evt.target like evt.target.gotoAndPlay('out');
}
```

Comment: I've to do everything in pure AS3. Any pointers in that context would be highly appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean "pure" as3?  As I see it, this answers your question quite precisely. You asked how to use an image such as a png as a button, and give it the ability to have rollover states.  The answer above tells you that.  The question of making multi-state and toggle buttons might be too advanced for your current as3 knowledge if you are not understanding the answer I gave.  Either that or you have not asked your question clearly enough.