# .PNG picture used as Button

Tags: actionscript-3, button

I am new.
I have cut out a picture in Photoshop and really want the picture to be the button. 
Allowing the button conforms to the shape of the image.

Example: This picture is what I mean: 
As you can see Europe & Asia has a square around it. If I make a button of this, it's like using a big square. It doesn't follow the shape of the map.

[image]

Comment: You want it where? Windows Forms, Qt, GTK, HTML?

Comment: your should've tagged your question accordingly. I did this for you.

Comment: So what exactly is the problem? Too lazy to read the manual for loading PNG? Or you got that but can't be bothered to check how to make things clickable... I'm not disrespecting, just showing you **how it looks** when you ask like this. Show & tell what you've tried and show where you are stuck.

Comment: I'm going to guess that your issue is you don't want the transparent areas of your PNG clickable (only the actual shape of the state).    The simplest way is to make a basic vector mask,however, that can be tedious for 50 objects, so you can check the pixel under the mouse for transparency.  See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30961458/1457439

Comment: This picture is what I mean: http://i.stack.imgur.com/VfZfH.png 
As you can see Europe & Asia has a square around it, so if I make a button of it, it is like a big square. I doesnt follow the shape of the map.

Comment: See **[this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5440370/2057709)**. Basically generate a new transparent bitmap from your PNG and no-colour pixels copied from the PNG will be click-thru... Another thing to try is to load the PNG image by code into a Sprite and also set same loaded image as a mask for Sprite (ie: image masks itself). Remember Sprite & MovieClips can respond to mouse events too (clicks, roll-over etc). PS: That box in the photo just for showing image area while you edit on the stage.

Comment: Also, there are plenty of world vector maps out there with all countries cut out as Vector shapes. This will solve your issues and also save a lot on the filesize :)

Comment: So what you mean VC.One is that I use BIT.MAP?
If you see here: https://gyazo.com/0c8f1f10d9dd7598c1097b5a0b90e1ed
(A better picture).
You guys see the "button-square" around "Skjak". When I want to move my mouse to "Lom", the "button-square" to "Skjak" is too big.
And I just want the square to follow the shape of the area.
Thank you so much guys for helping